# How to use Regex on Apache REQUEST_URI?

Tags: regex, apache, regex-group, ssi, request-uri

Currently using Apache 2.4 with SSI Legacy Parser On and trying to use Regex code to obtain the results I am looking for.

```
<!--#set var="test" value=$REQUEST_URI -->
<!--#echo var="test" -->
```

The example result I get from the above code is:

```
/path1/path2/path3/filename.html

/path1/path2/path3/filename.html?id=2019
```

The example result I would like to get is:

```
/path1/path2/path3/
```

Anything after the last forward slash removed regardless of the number of paths there may be.

Is there a regex code or something I could use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Here we can simply add a slash boundary and swipe everything from beginning to the last slash:

```
(.*)\/
```

The expression could stop right there, and it can be simply called using `$1`. However, we can also add more boundaries to it, if you wish, such as start and end chars:

```
^(.*)\/.*$
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uz4DQr/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /^(.*)\/.*$/gm;
const str = `/path1/path2/path3/filename.html
/path1/path2/path3/filename.html?id=2019
/path1/path2/path3/path4/filename.html?id=2019
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/filename.html?id=2019

`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: You got me in the right direction.....got it based off what you supplied.

 <!--#if expr="$REQUEST_URI = /^(.*)\/.*$/" -->
 <!--#set var="abspath" value="$1" -->
 <!--#endif -->
<!--#include virtual="${abspath}/whateverpage.shtml -->
<!--#include virtual="${abspath}/whateverFolder/whateverpage.shtml -->